# How to make widget working faster - custom json convert widget

Tags: flutter, dart, web

I have a list where I want to display a list of objects. Each object has a json field where "tags" are defined. Each consists of a field name and a value. The values from the fields contained in json have to be displayed in a nice looking form of "tiles". When a field is focused, the field name (ToolTip) should appears.

I wrote my widget that converts json for this. Works fine, but I've found that performance of list slows down much with number of items (scrolling and hovering over an item)
At 10 it is still ok, but at 50 it's not. When I comment "JsonWidget" and just use Text widget, everything works fast. I wonder if there is a way to write it in a more optimal way.

Her is full code:

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(GenistryApp());
}

//My example object with json field
class MyObject {
  int id;
  String json =
      '{"year":1850,"1 name":"Zuzanna","names":"Stefania","surname":"Zabłocka","sex":"W","city":"Warsaw","date":"1850.01.02","father":"Piotr","mothers_anme":"Józefa","mothers_surname":"Wojnicz","info":"Szlachetni"}';
  MyObject(this.id);
}

class GenistryApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const GenistryApp({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        home: MyTableWidget(),
        theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.lightGreen,
          visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
        ));
  }
}

class MyTableWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyTableWidget({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyTableWidgetState createState() => _MyTableWidgetState();
}

class _MyTableWidgetState extends State<MyTableWidget> {
  MyDataTableSource _data = MyDataTableSource([]);

  List<MyObject> list = [];

  //Generating 50 same elements for testing
  getData() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
      list.add(MyObject(i));
    }
    _data = MyDataTableSource(list);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    getData();
    return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.8),
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
          child: PaginatedDataTable(
            source: _data,
            columns: [
              DataColumn(label: Container()),
              DataColumn(
                  label: ConstrainedBox(
                      constraints: BoxConstraints.expand(
                          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width))),
            ],
            columnSpacing: 50,
            horizontalMargin: 10,
            rowsPerPage: 50,
            showCheckboxColumn: false,
          ),
        ));
  }
}

class MyDataTableSource extends DataTableSource {
  List<MyObject> _data;
  MyDataTableSource(this._data);

  bool get isRowCountApproximate => false;
  int get rowCount => _data.length;
  int get selectedRowCount => 0;
  DataRow getRow(int index) {
    return DataRow(cells: [
      DataCell(Text("ID")),
      DataCell(
        JsonWidget(_data[index]
            .json), //  Here is my widget to convert json field - it slows all list
        // Text(_data[index].json), //  Here is simple json field for testing - it works fast
        onTap: () => {},
      ),
    ]);
  }
}

//Widget to convert json to nice looking "tags"
class JsonWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  String jdata;
  Map<String, dynamic> data;
  JsonWidget(String jdata) {
    this.jdata = jdata;
  }
  var containers = <Tooltip>[];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    this.data = json.decode(this.jdata);
    data.entries.forEach((element) {
      containers.add(new Tooltip(
          message: element.key, //tag's fieldname
          textStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
          child: Container(
            margin: const EdgeInsets.all(3),
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4),
            child: Text(element.value.toString()), //tag's fieldvalue
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                border: Border.all(color: Colors.blueAccent, width: 0.7),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20))),
          )));
    });
    return Row(children: this.containers);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The build method is designed in such a way that it should be pure/without side effects. It should only return  a widget and not run for loops as in the JsonWidget case. A better way to write this will be using listview builder.

```
  class JsonWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  Map<String, dynamic> data;
  JsonWidget(Map<String, dynamic> data) {
    this.data = data;
  }
  var containers = <Tooltip>[];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
        shrinkWrap: true,
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        itemCount: data.entries.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return Tooltip(
              message: data.entries.toList()[index].key, //tag's fieldname
              textStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
              child: Container(
                margin: const EdgeInsets.all(3),
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4),
                child: Text(data.entries
                    .toList()[index]
                    .value
                    .toString()), //tag's fieldvalue
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    border: Border.all(color: Colors.blueAccent, width: 0.7),
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20))),
              ));
        });
  }
}
```

And MyDataTableSoure will look like this

```
class MyDataTableSource extends DataTableSource {
  List<MyObject> _data;
  MyDataTableSource(this._data);

  bool get isRowCountApproximate => false;
  int get rowCount => _data.length;
  int get selectedRowCount => 0;
  DataRow getRow(int index) {
    return DataRow(cells: [
      DataCell(Text("ID")),
      DataCell(
        JsonWidget(json.decode(_data[index]
            .json)), //  Here is my widget to convert json field - it slows all list
        // Text(_data[index].json), //  Here is simple json field for testing - it works fast
        onTap: () => {},
      ),
    ]);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestions. It looks better, but it has no effect to improvment of performance. It still slow with 50 elements.

Comment: Culd you try a  listview builder instead of the for loop. With listview it lazy loads

Comment: Yes. It's definitely better now. Do You know maybe if Listview is right to use for a large amount of data with pagination? Or Datatable is better?

Comment: The ListView builder supports lazy loading which is a must for big amounts of data because only the data visible on the screen is loaded with the ListView.builder and the construction based on the index. While Datatable is not responsible and doesnt lazy loads. For large amount of data  Paginated listview is  advisable.